# DeleteObject from multiple tables

Tags: c#, database, linq

I am trying to delete the movie from rentals table if it is selected from the listbox and it is working but i also need to remove datas connected to the movie from rentingpeople table

Rentals table contains the movieid which is in the listobox and personid which can be also found in rentingpeople and should get deleted the full row if they matches.

```
var search = (from g in db.Rentals where g.Movietitle == (string)lBfilmlista.SelectedValue select g).First();
foreach (var c in db.Rentingpeople where c.personid==search.personid).First();
{
     db.Rentingpeople.DeleteObject(c);
}
db.Rentals.DeleteObject(search);
db.SaveChanges();
```

there is code error at `where c.personid==search.personid`     ) ; expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with `First` at the end of `foreach` loop, and also mixing query syntax with method syntax.

So your code should be:

```
var search = (from g in db.Rentals where g.Movietitle == (string)lBfilmlista.SelectedValue select g).First();
var rowsToBeDeleted = db.Rentingpeople.Where(c=>  c.personid==search.personid).ToList(); 
foreach (var item in rowsToBeDeleted)
{
     db.Rentingpeople.DeleteObject(item);
}
db.Rentals.DeleteObject(search);
db.SaveChanges();
```

You can also setup [Cascade on Delete rules for your tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902684%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Comment: where: ) expected
c.personid: ; expected
search.personid:only assigment,call,....

at deleteobject c:c does not exist in current context

Comment: @user3551399, edited the answer with the complete code. Try it and see if it works.